# Why OneDrive displays itself incorrectly in wmic?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, onedrive, wmic

Try following line in command prompt with OneDrive working:

```
wmic process get Caption, ExecutablePath, ParentProcessId, ProcessId
```

You will see that there is one space difference after ExecutablePath if you compare OneDrive to all other programs. Why is that and how to fix that? (Believe it or not but this is actually important for me).

Output:

```
NvBackend.exe              C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\Update Core\NvBackend.exe                                              4168             5632       
SetPoint.exe               C:\Program Files\Logitech\SetPointP\SetPoint.exe                                                                 4168             5956       
svchost.exe                C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe                                                                                  780              6092       
OneDrive.exe               C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe                                                     4168             6120        
avastui.exe                C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\avastui.exe                                                                5564             4076
```

I use Windows 10.

Comment: Can't repro here. The spacing appears even.

Comment: That's interesting. Are all your processes even after you call command? In my case there is always problem with OneDrive.

Comment: Whatever it *is* you're doing, it would probably be easier in PowerShell. :)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Agree with @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 to use Powershell and deal with objects rather than spacing.

Comment: Sigh. Hoped that it won't come to that. So it's time to learn power shell now. Programers can't catch a break.

Comment: @Gunnm It won't bite, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx